# cakephp reloading page and passing param

Tags: session, cakephp, reload

i have a page that gives the option to keep adding fields to a template or post the final field and then go to the index page. When a user creates a template they are taken to create a field. the `template.id` is put in the `field.template_id` but when a user selects to add another field, i lose `field.template_id`.

here is the code of my function

```
function add($last=null){

    $this->set('title_for_layout', 'Create Fields');
    $this->set('stylesheet_used', 'homestyle');
    $this->set('image_used', 'eBOXLogoHome.png');
    $this->layout='home_layout';

        //retrieve Account Id of current User       
        $accountid=$this->Auth->user('account_id');


        $this->set('accountid', $accountid); 

    if($this->request->is('post'))
    {

    $this->Field->create(); 

    if ($this->Field->save($this->request->data))
    {   
        if($this->request->data['submit'] == "type_1") 
            {

                $last=$this->Field->read('template_id');
                $this->Session->setFlash('The field has been saved');  
                $this->redirect( array('controller' => 'fields','action' => 'add', $last));
            } 
            if($this->request->data['submit'] == "type_2") 
            { 
                $this->Session->setFlash('The template has been saved'); 
                $this->redirect( array('controller' => 'templates','action' => 'index'));
            } 


    }
    else
    {
        $this->Session->setFlash('The field could not be saved. Please, try again.'); 
    } 
 }
     $this->set('accounts', $accounts); 
     $this->set('last', $last); 


  }

}
```

the problem im having is when a user clicks `type_1` and it reloads the page its not grabbing the `template_id` and inserting it in the `field.template_id`

Comment: Not clear what exactly the error?

Comment: When I go to type1 the template_id isn't available in the form/URL etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your code, it looks that you are finding $last whenever your form is posted to the add() method. Move this field find condition outside the `if($this->request->is('post'))` and it will be done.

As the read method overwrites any information stored in the data and id property of the model, you should be very careful when using this function in general, especially using it in the model callback functions such as beforeValidate and beforeSave. Generally the find function provides a more robust and easy to work with API than the read method.

http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/retrieving-your-data.html#model-read

Comment: if I do this, it doesnt grab the template.id after I originally create template.id and am redirected to this page. Also after manually entering the $last into the field it doesn't keep it there